# Reading Variables from .Properties file into Javascript/HTML pages Running in a NodeJS Server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a properties file called "site.properties" and in it I have:

```
#Properties file
#Database Connection Info
  db.host.name = localhost
  db.user.name = username
  db.password = password
  db.database.schema = db1

#Server Connection Info
  server.url.host.name = localhost
  server.port = 3000
```

In my server.js file I am reading in the properties using PropertiesReader:

```
var PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
var properties = PropertiesReader('./site.properties');

var hostName = properties.get('db.host.name');
var dbUser = properties.get('db.user.name');
var dbPassword = properties.get('db.password');
var dbDatabaseSchema = properties.get('db.database.schema');
var host = properties.get('server.url.host.name');
var port = properties.get('server.port');
```

I have successfully been able to use db variables to connect but I need the server variables in the .js files I have in my site. I have tried to use:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render("./views/index.html", {host:host});
  res.render("./views/index.html", {port:port});

});
```

But when I try to read the variables on the webpage I am unable to get the variable value. ( I have used two different ways to read in the variable and neither worked)

```
<script>
 var host = "<%= host %>";
 var port = "{{port}}";
 console.log(host);
 console.log(port);
```

Any ideas on how to fix this or a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to console in your server first host and port to be sure you get them from properties file, other thing you should have one res.render and no need to write the whole url only the file name index and the file should be index.ejs not .html, hope this helps you.

```js
res.render('index',{ 
                            Host : host, 
                            Port : port
                            }
                );
```

Comment: I tried this out but still not getting the variable values in the html page. I have console printed the values from the node side and I am getting the correct values from the properties file.

Comment: try to change the extension of your index.html to index.ejs and make Host and Port upper case.